# Solving $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to solve? $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}$$
I can't use any L'Hôpital or Cauchy rules, only basic limits operations.

Comment: What tools can you use? Do you know what are Taylor's polynomials or L'Hopital rule?

Comment: Did you mean $x\to 0$ or $x\to 1$?

Comment: The limit isn't even indeterminate. Surely you must've at least tried something before asking this here. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I would suspect the limiting value of $x$ is incorrect and the intent was L'Hopitals...

Comment: Just updated question.

Comment: Can you confirm the limit is 0 or 1 for $x$? If it is $0$ you need no tricks, only the knowledge that $\ln x \to -\infty$ as $x\downarrow 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\ln(x)=-\infty$

Comment: Actually I got stuck in that, I don't know why I didn't simply think in that. When things are simple it seems that we complicate them.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln x}{1-x} = \left(\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ln x\right)\left( \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{1-x}\right) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ln x = -\infty
$$
If you meant $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \ln x /\left(1-x\right)$,
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{\ln x}{1-x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}\ln x}{\frac{d}{dx}\left(1-x\right)} = - \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{1}{x} = -1
$$